# updating WSDL for http to https change

Tags: java, web-services, http, https

We have developed a web service in Java and have published the wsdl. This is done over http. Now we have to provide it over a secure connection i.e. https. The web service application is hosted on webspehere and we have the certificate used in websphere for https.

I am looking for the steps to update the java code and wsdl so that we can publish web service over https.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to update any Java code or WSDLs.  This is all a function of the server configuration.  The server is already listening on regular HTTP, presumably on port 80.  A listener needs to be added for HTTPS, presumably on port 443 - and mapped to the same web context as your existing application.

Alternatively, this can be done outside of the web server (WebSphere, in your case) by fronting it with something like Apache HTTP Server or a dedicated load balancer that supports SSL/TLS offloading - which can be more efficient.

Since this really isn't a programming question, I'd recommend opening a new question at http://serverfault.com for details on how to configure WebSphere or something related to the configuration I proposed above.